# vba 4 conditions mistake not execution well

Tags: vba

Perhaps it was already debated here.What I am pretending is to hide/unhide a row interval depending on cell C3. If C3 is not one of the following numbers 1,2,3 or 4 it is suppose to hide rows 7 to 19 click on a button. If is equal to 1 it is suppose shows rows 7 to 8, If is equal to 2 it is suppose shows rows 7 to 12 and so on.

It seems that the code as i wrote it need to follow a certain path otherwise it does not work.

I hope to have been clear.
thank you all

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your question might be clearer if you included a [mcve] that reproduced the specific problem you're having (can be your actual code, if it's self-contained), and described what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If the rows to hide/unhide are dependent on the value in C3, why use a button at all? Simply hide/unhide when the value in C3 changes.

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code. Paste this into the worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, "C")) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Cells(3, "C").Value2
            Case 1
                Rows("7:9").Hidden = True
                Rows("10:19").Hidden = False
            Case 2
                Rows("7:12").Hidden = True
                Rows("13:19").Hidden = False
            Case 3
                'and so on
            Case 4
                'and so on
            Case Else
                Rows("7:19").Hidden = False
        End Select

    End If

End Sub
```